# R complete values using conditions in certain columns based on groups

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got a dataset that looks like this.

```
dataset = data.frame(SiteID= c(rep('1001',5),rep('1002',7),rep('1003',10),rep('1004',3)),
                     Site = c(rep('x',5),rep('w',7),rep('y',10),rep('z',3)),
                     Parent_Company = c(rep('NULL',2),rep('X LTD.',1),rep('X LTD.',2),rep('NULL',1),rep('W LTD.',6),rep('Y LTD.',8),rep('NULL',2),rep('Z LTD.',3)),
                     Country=c(rep('USA',5),rep('UK',7),rep('Japan',10),rep('Australia',3)),
                     Region=c(rep('NORAM',5),rep('UK&I',7),rep('ASIA',10),rep('OCEANIA',3)),
                     Audited= c(rep('Yes',3),rep('No',2),rep('Yes',6),rep('No',1),rep('Yes',10),rep('No',3)))
```

I'm trying to clean up a few columns, namely `Parent_Company` and `Audited`. I'm looking for the most efficient way to do so.

**What I'd like to achieve -**

1. For the `Parent_Company` column - If a given site has *at least* one value in the `Parent_Company` column, and the rest are 'NULL', then the 'NULL's should be replaced with that value. If there are no values and only 'NULL's then nothing is to be replaced.
2. For the `Audited` column - If a given site has at least one 'Yes' in the `Audited` column, then all other values need to be 'Yes'. If there are only 'No's, then nothing is changed.

**My attempt**

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

    output = dataset %>%
      group_by(Site,SiteID,Country,Region) %>%
      mutate(Parent_Company = case_when(any(Parent_Company == "NULL") ~ Parent_Company,
                                       TRUE ~ "NULL")) %>%
      mutate(Audited = case_when(any(Audited == "Yes") ~ "Yes",
                                        TRUE ~ "No"))
```

Seems to work for the `Audited` column. But not for `Parent_Company`. Any help would be appreciated.

**My desired output**

```
output = data.frame(SiteID= c(rep('1001',5),rep('1002',7),rep('1003',10),rep('1004',3)),
                     Site = c(rep('x',5),rep('w',7),rep('y',10),rep('z',3)),
                     Parent_Company = c(rep('X LTD.',5),rep('W LTD.',7),rep('Y LTD.',10),rep('Z LTD.',3)),
                     Country=c(rep('USA',5),rep('UK',7),rep('Japan',10),rep('Australia',3)),
                     Region=c(rep('NORAM',5),rep('UK&I',7),rep('ASIA',10),rep('OCEANIA',3)),
                     Audited= c(rep('Yes',5),rep('Yes',7),rep('Yes',10),rep('No',3)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. I don't think you need `case_when` here, which would be justified if you had more than one condition; the `if_else` is sufficient for `Parent_Company`, and frankly a standard `if` works for `Audited` (using "recycling", i.e., auto-repeating a value to the desired length of the vector).

```r
dataset %>%
  group_by(Site, SiteID, Country, Region) %>%
  mutate(
    Parent_Company = if_else(Parent_Company == "NULL" & any(Parent_Company != "NULL"),
                             Parent_Company[Parent_Company != "NULL"][1], Parent_Company),
    Audited = if (any(Audited == "Yes")) "Yes" else Audited
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 25 x 6
#    SiteID Site  Parent_Company Country Region Audited
#    <chr>  <chr> <chr>          <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  
#  1 1001   x     X LTD.         USA     NORAM  Yes    
#  2 1001   x     X LTD.         USA     NORAM  Yes    
#  3 1001   x     X LTD.         USA     NORAM  Yes    
#  4 1001   x     X LTD.         USA     NORAM  Yes    
#  5 1001   x     X LTD.         USA     NORAM  Yes    
#  6 1002   w     W LTD.         UK      UK&I   Yes    
#  7 1002   w     W LTD.         UK      UK&I   Yes    
#  8 1002   w     W LTD.         UK      UK&I   Yes    
#  9 1002   w     W LTD.         UK      UK&I   Yes    
# 10 1002   w     W LTD.         UK      UK&I   Yes    
# # ... with 15 more rows
```

If you really want `case_when` (e.g., there are more conditions for a particular column than you've stated here, then:

```r
dataset %>%
  group_by(Site, SiteID, Country, Region) %>%
  mutate(
    Parent_Company = case_when(
      Parent_Company == "NULL" & any(Parent_Company != "NULL") ~ Parent_Company[Parent_Company != "NULL"][1],
      TRUE ~ Parent_Company),
    Audited = case_when(
      Audited != "Yes" & any(Audited == "Yes") ~ "Yes",
      TRUE ~ Audited)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 25 x 6
#    SiteID Site  Parent_Company Country Region Audited
#    <chr>  <chr> <chr>          <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  
#  1 1001   x     X LTD.         USA     NORAM  Yes    
#  2 1001   x     X LTD.         USA     NORAM  Yes    
#  3 1001   x     X LTD.         USA     NORAM  Yes    
#  4 1001   x     X LTD.         USA     NORAM  Yes    
#  5 1001   x     X LTD.         USA     NORAM  Yes    
#  6 1002   w     W LTD.         UK      UK&I   Yes    
#  7 1002   w     W LTD.         UK      UK&I   Yes    
#  8 1002   w     W LTD.         UK      UK&I   Yes    
#  9 1002   w     W LTD.         UK      UK&I   Yes    
# 10 1002   w     W LTD.         UK      UK&I   Yes    
# # ... with 15 more rows
```

Comment: r2evans, could you please explain what "na.omit(Parent_Company)[1]" does?

Comment: Something I noticed - the bit of code `na.omit(dataset$Parent_Company)[1]` takes the first value of `Parent_Company` and replaces the NULLs with this value. However, in a situation where `na.omit(dataset$Parent_Company)[1]`  happens to be "NULL", the solution doesn't work. Is there a way to ensure that instead of fixing an index, it looks for the non-NULL mention of `Parent_Company` anywhere within the group and replaces it?

Comment: `na.omit` is only used if: *this* value is `"NULL"`, **and** *any* values is not `"NULL"`. Frankly, we don't need the `na.omit`, that's a mistake from an earlier iteration, stby ...

Comment: @r2evans I've slightly modified the dataset to change the sequence of "NULL"s in the `Parent_Company` column

Comment: Both sets of code produce your desired `output`, did I miss something? (With the edit to replace `na.omit`, that is.)

Comment: r2evans, wouldn't grouping by just "Site" column suffice? Any reason you've grouped by multiple columns.

Comment: @KarthikS perhaps ... I was going completely by the grouping that the OP provided in the sample code. I'm assuming that there are properties of the *real* data that suggest that is the preferred way to go for them.

Answer (score 0):

The Parent_Company cannot succeed because your telling R that if Parent_Company==NULL then it should take on the value of Parent_Company, but which one? It will just use for each row the Parent_Company value of that row, so you get the same as you already had

So to fix this you can instead write:

```
dataset %>% group_by(Site,SiteID,Country,Region) %>%
  mutate(
    Parent_Company = case_when(any(!is.null(Parent_Company)) ~ .$Parent_Company[1]),
    Audited = case_when(any(Audited == "Yes") ~ "Yes",  TRUE ~ "No")
    )
```

Meaning: when any Parent_Company of the group is not NULL, than apply the first Parent_Company value to all (assuming that all Parent_Company values are the same; NULL will be droped in any list, so it will not be used).

Comment: `is.null` doesn't work when looking for the literal string `"NULL"`. It's impossible for a simple column in a frame (with one or more rows) to have a literal `NULL`; the only way to have a real `NULL` in a frame is using list-columns, which this data does not contain.